# Can't download file throught ftp with ascii mode

Tags: networking, command-line, server, ftp

I'm trying to download file from my own ftp server, but there's a problem, when I try to do it with `ascii` option. Download goes for 1-2sec and then fails like this:

```
local: BF1.TXT remote: BF1.TXT
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||28037|)
150 Open file... 
  8576 KiB    8.37 MiB/s ftp: Reading from network: Interrupted system call
    -1        0.00 KiB/s 
226 finished
WARNING! 4304 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode.
File may not have transferred correctly.
221 Good bye!
```

When I use `binary`:

```
local: BF1.TXT remote: BF1.TXT
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||2288|)
150 Open file... 
 34425 KiB    8.28 MiB/s 
226 finished
35251201 bytes received in 00:04 (8.16 MiB/s)
221 Good bye!
```

Also after checking with wireshark, I saw that in `ascii` client send RST ACK packet, but i don't really get why. Is there some problem with server? Or is it client fault?

**P.S.**
Tried to download file with Filezilla(uses `ascii` option), Double Commander(uses `binary`) and lftp (used both types of transfer) all attempts were successful.